# How to set Android environment variables for app to inherit?

Tags: android, shell, environment-variables, adb

I use `adb shell` to debug app, and set some env variable like this `export TESTVAR=test`, then I start app in the same shell `am start -n my.app.package`, strangely the process cannot see `TESTVAR` (examine `/proc/pid/environ`) because the app process's parent is **zygote**. How to set the env for such app processes?

Comment: It's said /system/bin/app_process is the zygote's executable, maybe an app can be started via it. Are there any files for *init* and *zygote* process to read as environment variables to spawn it child processes? /system/bin/sh really have one, /system/etc/mkshrc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using environment variables for testing purposes, and do not have functionalities that will depend on them in production, this answer may be helpful. However, if you're interfacing and using JNI libraries and want to use environment variables as a directive for those libraries then I'm not sure if it's usable.

In API 21, Google introduced [Os](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html) class to expose system-level access to developers. I haven't tried it so far, but it's supposed to be the interface between Android app and underlying Linux kernel. Which is, hopefully, what you need. There is, of course, [setenv](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#setenv(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) method which delegates the parameters you set to Linux's [setenv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) method.

Like I wrote, I'm not sure if this is viable and dependable in production, and this class requires API level 21 and I don't know which Android version you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks @NitroNbg, Environment variables like LD_XXX are useful for debugging purpose in Android, I need to alter these variables when an app starts, maybe an app can be started using */system/bin/app_process* (the old name of zygote) command line, still have no idea after googled a lot.

Comment: I am on Android API 28 and unfortunately the Os.setenv() doesn't work as intended. I tried to set some env variable using setenv before loading a lib with System.loadLibrary(). The loaded lib did not work as expected.